# Ember data batched loading

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a page with many records on it and it's slow to load. What I'd like to do is load the records in batches.

Let's say there are 1000 records in total and I want to load 30 at a time. Looking at the page you would see records being added in groups of 30 and the page would grow longer until all records have been loaded.

How would I go about customising the RESTAdaptor from ember-data? Ideally I'd be able to do something like:

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  revision: 4,
  adapter: App.RESTAdapter.create({
    batchsize: "30"
  })
});
```

Comment: You might not need to customize the REST Adapter. This answer might help you get started. It certainly helped me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11907093/infinite-scroll-with-ember-js-lazy-loading